# What happens when you set a DOM property with JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm wondering what JS does behind the scenes when I do something like `ele.scrollLeft = 200;` because I recently ran into a bug.

For example, I have an element with `scroll-behavior` set to smooth, and then I run the following:

```
document.getElementById('a').scrollLeft = 300;
console.log(document.getElementById('a').scrollLeft);
```

Rather than printing 300, this prints 0. I am confused because if this behaves like a regular JS object, what I would expect is it to be set to 300, then after my call stack finishes, it will then change the value to whatever (in this case 0 because of scroll-behavior). Instead, it seems to somehow pause my call stack execution and do something behind the scenes before returning back to me, as if it was a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

Comment: Good to know. Do you have a link explaining why they are better? Couldn't find it myself

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans differences which are... ? The only one I can see is that the scrollLeft's setter will call the scrollTop getter, while scrollTo will directly use "the element’s current scroll position on the y axis", but I'm afraid this actually boils to exactly the same, and as for `scrollBy` it will also explicitely call the scrollTop getter, so `scrollBy({ left })` is exactly the same as `scrollLeft = left`, except that it uses a dictionary. Am I missing something here? Where did you read that it's preferable to call the methods?

Comment: mostly the additional pre-steps, but maybe I was misreading the spec

Answer (score 1):

The DOM does live outside of the JS context, what we have access in JS are wrappers around the actual DOM objects.
Most of these wrapper objects's properties are [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set). Setting it will call a function that may produce something and maybe change a value. Getting it will also call a function which may also produce something or return a cached value. For instance getting the `.scrollLeft` value of an Element may trigger a recalc of the CSS boxes, because these boxes need to be up to date for the engine to return the correct value.

Now, what the [scrollLeft setter](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrollleft) utlimately does is to call the [scroll the element](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scroll-an-element) algorithm. This algorithm will eventually change the scrolling position of the element, but with a scroll behavior of `"smooth"` this won't happen until at least the next painting frame. When you call the getter, it returns the current scroll position. So if you call this getter before the scroll actually began, you'll indeed have the same value as before you did call the setter.